# Oracle SQL Join and Count Case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a course where students are enroled by year and they have records of attendance and I need to know from the total enroled per year how many actually attended to the course, what would be the SQL query needed to achieve that?

Expected output:

```
YEAR COURSE ENROLED ATTENDED
---- ------ ------- --------
2017 IT           3        2
2018 IT           2        0
```

Sample Oracle script:

```
--
DROP TABLE ATTENDANCE;
DROP TABLE ENROLMENT;
DROP TABLE STUDENT;
DROP TABLE COURSE;
--
CREATE TABLE COURSE (ID VARCHAR2(1), NAME VARCHAR2(20), PRIMARY KEY(ID));
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (ID VARCHAR2(1), NAME VARCHAR2(20), PRIMARY KEY(ID));
CREATE TABLE ENROLMENT (ID VARCHAR2(1), COURSE_ID VARCHAR2(1), STUDENT_ID VARCHAR2(1), YEAR VARCHAR2(4), PRIMARY KEY(COURSE_ID, STUDENT_ID, YEAR));
CREATE TABLE ATTENDANCE (ENROLMENT_ID VARCHAR2(1), PRIMARY KEY(ENROLMENT_ID));
--
INSERT INTO COURSE VALUES('1', 'IT');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('1', 'John');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('2', 'Mary');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('3', 'Peter');
INSERT INTO ENROLMENT VALUES('1', '1', '1', '2017');
INSERT INTO ENROLMENT VALUES('2', '1', '2', '2017');
INSERT INTO ENROLMENT VALUES('3', '1', '3', '2017');
INSERT INTO ENROLMENT VALUES('4', '1', '1', '2018');
INSERT INTO ENROLMENT VALUES('5', '1', '2', '2018');
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('1');
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('2');
COMMIT;
--
```

Comment: Looks like `oracle` from the title.

Comment: Yes, the database is Oracle

Comment: SELECT 
E.YEAR,
C.NAME,
COUNT(S.ID) ENROLED
FROM 
COURSE C
LEFT JOIN ENROLMENT E
ON C.ID = E.COURSE_ID
LEFT JOIN STUDENT S
ON E.STUDENT_ID = S.ID
GROUP BY E.YEAR, C.NAME
ORDER BY E.YEAR, C.NAME;

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
select e.year, c.name, 
    count(distinct s.id) as enroled, 
    count(distinct a.enrolment_id) as attended
  from enrolment e
  join course c on e.course_id = c.id
  left join student s on s.id = e.student_id
  left join attendance a on a.enrolment_id = e.id
  group by e.year, c.name
```

Result:

```
year  name  enroled  attended
----  ----  -------  -----
2017  IT    3        2
2018  IT    2        0
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot, my sql is so rusty,,,